# How to have two timers for Java game applet

Tags: java, oop, timer, applet, countdowntimer

I require two timers. One to run the game e.g move objects, and perform checks and another as a countdown timer. I have tried the following:

```
Timer countdownTimer = new Timer(1000,this);
Timer gameTimer = new Timer(30,this);

public void init()
{
   this.actionPerformed(this); //add action listener to content pane
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource() == gameTimer)
    {
        // control the game
    }

    if(e.getSource() == countdownTimer)
    {
       //decremenet the timer
    }
}
```

However this returns a Null pointer exception when I try to run the applet. How do I properly distinguish each timer from the other and perform the desired actions at each timer tick. Thanks

Comment: Where does it throw the Exception? Is that really a `NullPointerException`? Not a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: it is a java.lang.NullPointerException. 
And when I click the error it redirects to the first if in the actionPerformed method

Comment: It would mean that the `e` is `null`? Are you calling that `actionPerformed()` method yourself passing it a `null` as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the `javax.swing.Timer` class?
`this.actionPerformed(this);` does not seem right, as your applet is not an `ActionEvent`.
Besides, you should start the timers in the `init()` method:

```
public class GameApplet extends Appel implements ActionListener
    public void init()
    {
        countdownTimer = new Timer(1000,this);
        gameTimer = new Timer(30,this);
        countdownTimer.start();
        gameTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == gameTimer) {
            // control the game
        }

        if(e.getSource() == countdownTimer) {
           //decremenet the timer
        }
    }
}
```

Check the [Timer javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that also redirects to the [Java tutorial about Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: I have tried you solution. It works however I still get a Null Pointer exception when the applet runs then the timer function properly.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: One thing comes to mind: http://religion.blogs.cnn.com/2010/06/02/a-mandala-in-minutes/ :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 it's well deserved, really :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ScheduledExecutorService. It is more efficient than timer. To see its effect run following   code.

```
class GameControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForGame() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Game");
            }
        };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
                scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 30, 30, SECONDS);
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                beeperHandle.cancel(true);
            }
        }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
    }

    public void beepCountDown() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("count down");
            }
        };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
                scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 1, 1, SECONDS);
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                beeperHandle.cancel(true);
            }
        }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameControl bc=new GameControl();
        bc.beepCountDown();
        bc.beepForGame();
    }
}
```